# Can we query Custom Notifications sent to a user or channel?

Tags: notification

I know we can query [Custom Notification TYPES](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_customnotificationtype.htm) or we can send custom notifications through apex and/or Rest API.

But can we fetch the open (or even all) notifications sent to a user?

For further context, we have an external application that shows data from Salesforce in real time and we would like to check if there are any open notifications for the current user and show them alongside the other notifications from this App.

Comment: Have you tried to update the notifications through a PATCH request? I am trying to do that but it throws BAD REQUEST error. I posted a question for that https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/385225/update-notification-through-connect-notification-api?noredirect=1#comment557360_385225

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably use GET method in Salesforce Action REST API. I don't think there is any other way currently.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_custom_notification.htm

edit:
actually, you probably could also use connect REST API and that would be even better idea: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_notifications_list.htm

Comment: Nice. Fresh out of the oven.