# Update notification through connect notification api

Tags: notification, connect-api

I have been trying to execute a Patch request to /connect/notifications api by sending the following payload from developer console. But I get the response as Bad Request, error code 400.

{
"before": "2019-06-25T18:24:31.000Z",
"read" : "true"
}

If I execute the request from workbench, it works fine and returns an empty notifications[]. Has anyone been able to send a Patch request from dev console.

Here is the code I am using.

```
    String sfdcURL = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm(); 

String restAPIURL = sfdcURL + '/services/data/v51.0/connect/notifications';
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();  

httpRequest.setMethod('PATCH');

httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID()); 
httpRequest.setEndpoint(restAPIURL);
String body = '{' +
    '\"before\" : \"2019-06-25T18:24:31.000Z\",' +    
    '\"read\" : \"true\"' +
    '}';
httpRequest.setBody(body);

String response = '';
try {  
    Http http = new Http();   
    HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);  
    if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200 ) {  
        response = JSON.serializePretty( JSON.deserializeUntyped(httpResponse.getBody()) );     
    }
} catch( System.Exception e) {  
    System.debug('ERROR: '+ e);  
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and post your code from Dev Console.

Comment: @SarojBera - have added the callout code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have add the `Content-Type` header as below. It is missing, that's why you are getting the *Bad Request* error.

```
httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID()); 
httpRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
httpRequest.setEndpoint(restAPIURL);
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much for the answer.